# Serializing and deserializing Java generics using Jackson: StackOverflowError

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm currently working on a model which uses generics and is little complicated. I understand that similar questions have been answered but none of them clearly answers mine.

Here is my model:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
              { 
                  @Type(value = Cls2.class, name = "Cls2") 
              })
abstract class Cls1<T> implements Serializable
{
    private T myObj;

    public T getMyObj()
    {
        return myObj;
    }

    public Cls1(T obj)
    {
        myObj = obj;
    }
    @JsonTypeName("Cls2")
    public static class Cls2<E extends Int1> extends Cls1<E> implements Serializable
    {
        public Cls2()
        {
            super(null);
        }
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("ChildContainer")
class ChildContainer extends ParentContainer<OtherBean>
{

}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
              { 
                  @Type(value = ChildContainer.class, name = "ChildContainer") 
              })
class ParentContainer<T extends RootBean> implements Int1
{

}

@JsonTypeName("OtherBean")
class OtherBean extends RootBean
{

}

@JsonTypeName("RootBean")
class RootBean implements Int1
{

}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
              { 
                  @Type(value = RootBean.class, name = "RootBean"),
                  @Type(value = OtherBean.class, name = "OtherBean")
              })
interface Int1 extends Serializable
{

}
```

My goal is to serialize and deserialze using jackson as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        Cls2<ChildContainer> req = new Cls2<ChildContainer>();

        File file = new File("==some-file-path==");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.writeValue(file, req);

        //read it back using mapper.readValue(file, clazz) --Not sure about this
    }
```

I get the following java.lang.StackOverflowError during the serialization:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:951)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:493)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:395)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:951)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:493)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:395)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:290)
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Posting the (repeated) part of the stack, from the error message or as captured in a debugger, would definitely help determine where the circularity occurs.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I have updated the post with stacktrace

Comment: There's an infinite recursion in type resolving which seems to be a bug in Jackson. Try extracting `Cls2` into a standalone class.

Comment: @BalusC Brilliant !! I have been facing this issue from past one hour. Thanks :)

Comment: @BalusC How about deserialization. How do I say Cls2<ChildContainer>.class ? in readValue() ?

Comment: I reposted it as an answer. As to the new question, press `Ask Question`. This is offtopic (and actually beyond me as I've never used Jackson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests an infinite recursion in type resolving of `Cls2` which extends the class it is by itself nested in. This seems to be a corner case bug in Jackson ([report it](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON)!). In the meanwhile, extracting `Cls2` into a standalone class instead of nesting it in its superclass should solve this problem.